# which version of redis supports both clustering and replication?

Tags: redis

I want to use Redis. Is there any stable release of Redis which supports both clustering and replication? Is Redis-V8 differs from Redis ? If Yes, then what are the differences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no stable official release of Redis which supports clustering and replication. What is provided by Redis is master/slave replication, plus role management (redis-sentinel). You still need to take care of data distribution, and resource management, to get a proper cluster.

Redis-V8 is a one-man fork replacing Lua by V8. Its user base is probably very narrow, compared to official Redis.

Comment: Is there any disadvantage of using redis-v8?

Comment: Less tested, less deployed, so probably more bugs. Less releases, so less bug fixes. No support from the Redis community. Now if you prefer JavaScript over Lua, how about giving it a try and decide by yourself?

Comment: ok thanks.Now I am not using it.